# Folders created by Program causes read-only to appear

Tags: windows, powershell, folder-permissions

So, I stumbled across a little problem, I can't seem to figure out.
I have a NAS where I dump data on and a script to download files I need back to my PC.
While doing so, it creates a folder for the file. After that, I run a different script that encodes the video files to save some space.
However, for some reason, the files and folders keep getting a 'read-only' lock that prevents the source file to be deleted after compression.
So I have to get into each individual folder and remove the read-only permission.

Is there some way to disable the read-only lock?
The Owner if the Root folder is my personal account, with full access.
Changing it to SYSTEM or Admin with full access doesn't change anything.

Comment: are you sure that it is read-only ... and not "this is still in use"?

Comment: when I click on Properties, the read-only is checked, so yes, it's read-only

Comment: i recommend you dig into your NAS setup. it may be a setting on that side that is the source of the R-O. ///// another possible source is the util you are using to copy the files. ///// beyond that, i am out of ideas. [*sigh ...*]

Comment: The read only attribute will not stop you from deleting the files.  The read only attribute prevents the file from being edited.  I would have to see a code sample to be sure, but I think you may have a line of code that is locking the file.  Are you using the New-Object commandlet?